# Is List & Label Standard edition ok with .NET Framework AnyCPU "Prefer 32-bit"?

Tags: listlabel

I am currently evaluating List & Label. The edition comparison seems to indicate that the Standard edition cannot be used by 64-bit programs, and I also got that confirmed by the company making the product. However, what I need to know is the following.

I plan to use List & Label in a Visual Studio solution with projects compiled for AnyCPU with "Prefer 32-bit" set.

Is there anybody out there that runs the licensed Standard edition with AnyCPU and "Prefer 32-bit" set on a 64-bit machine? It would be nice to know for certain whether it works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will work. See [What AnyCPU Really Means As Of .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/) to confirm this will start a 32 bit process on all platforms supported by List & Label:

> - If the process runs on a 32-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.
> - If the process runs on a 64-bit Windows system, it runs as a 32-bit process. IL is compiled to x86 machine code.

Comment: I understand that part, and I consider the probability very high that that's what List & Label checks, but I won't disregard the possibility that it checks some compile time information and conclude it isn't 32-bit. I will just have to order the Standard product, and see what happens. I'll report back here in a few days.

Comment: I work for combit - rest assured it will work and there are no additional checks :)

Comment: Ah! No reason do doubt you then. Thank you very much. Great product by the way.